# Why do I get RecursionError only for 1 case using the same variable when inserting an item in dynamoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I am seeing a really strange behaviour in python 3, and boto3 when inserting an item to dynamoDB.

```
# Assume that set_original() returns a dictionary
original = set_original()

# copy is an EXACT copy of original, but hardcoded.
copy = {..hardcoded "original" dictionary..}
```

I can confirm that both dictionaries are the same, as the following returns True:

```
if copy == original:
    return True
```

Right now this is failing with an enormous `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

```
table.put_item(Item=original)
```

But this works just fine and successfully inserts the data in dynamodb:

```
table.put_item(Item=copy)
```

What can possibly be happening? I checked and type(), and dir() return the same for both, they are basically copies of each other, but only one fails to insert, while the other one doesn't.

Comment: [This comment on and issue in the DynamoDB github repo](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2071#issuecomment-538522203) might explain the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know the exact reason on why this is happening, I solved as follows:
`set_original()` was creating a dict in which one of the variables was not a str, but rather a beautiful soup string:
`<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>`
This is okay for python, but it's not okay for dynamoDB. Solution was basically to convert all these NavigableString to `str` type.